# Where is "Regular Solids" option?

Tags: mesh, add-on

Following an online tutorial that uses an object named "icosahedron" from Add > Mesh > Regular Solids > Archimedean > Icosahedron. This object is not available in my version of Blender (2.74). Presenter asks me to include an add-on named "Add Mesh: Regular Solids", which again is not listed in my User Preferences dialog. What can I do about it?

Comment: You put "Add Mesh:Regular Solids" into google, like here look: https://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app&gws_rd=ssl#q=Add+Mesh:+Regular+Solids and you click the first link, wow - instant success! There you will learn its now obsolete and the new addon is named "Add Extra Objects" with link to it.

Comment: @Jerryno: Thanks a bunch. I hate posting questions that would have taken one Google visit to get answers for. In this case too, I actually performed some searches before coming here, but it looks like I missed checking out that particular result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The plugin you need is called now **add_mesh_extra_objects**.
To enable it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to open the preferences window.
On the Addons tab type extra and and check the box for Add Mesh:Extra Objects

[image]

There are new options on the add mesh menu. Select Math Function Solid.

[image]

On the tools tab (<kbd>T</kbd>) select Icosahedron

[image]

Alternatively press <kbd>F6</kbd> to access the option for the tool.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Blender 2.8+
First go to EDIT > Preferences >Add ons > Add Mesh : Extra Objects and then close the preferences window.
Then In Object mode > Add > Mesh >Scroll down to Math Funtion > Regular Solid
and then refer the below image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: "Custom" Options]
Click "Custom" then "Truncated Icosahedron" for the soccer ball tutorial instead of clicking under "Source". It is under "Custom" that it will show you different solids you may use including the Truncated Icosahedron.