# Making regular polyhedra in Blender using Python

Tags: python, modeling, geometry

How can I make regular polyhedra in Blender such as tetrahedron, octahedron, dodecahedron and icosahedron so that their vertices lie on a sphere with radius `r`? I eventually want to write Python code to do this. That's why I think an add-on like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31292/where-is-regular-solids-option) would not be useful for me as it seems that I cannot install add-ons using Python and work with them (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is "Regular Solids" option?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31292/where-is-regular-solids-option)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I should have mentioned that I looked at that post but I do not want to do it with add-ons because I want to do everything in Python, eventually. It seems that it's not possible to use some of the add-ons in Python. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I assume  "by Python" you mean you are using `bpy` as a python module,.  You can install addons using python. Look at `addon_utils.enable`.  The  regular solids  addon is written in python, could import a method from it (`add_mesh_extra_objects.add_mesh_solid`), or cut and paste into another script. Lastly could use the addon to create object and  make a list of the vert coords, face and edge indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's easy (**a bit hacky though**) to make such regular shapes in Blender without using add-ons. Here's how:

**Tetrahedron**
Bring up the Add Mesh menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), and select a Cone. Set the number of Vertices to 3, leave Radius 1 at its default value of `1.000` and Radius 2 at `0.000`. Now, set the Depth to square root of `2 =~ 1.414213`

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=3, depth=1.414213)
```

**Octahedron**
This shape is the dual of the cube -- it has vertices where the cube has faces, and faces where the cube has vertices. To make it, first create a cube. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch to Edit mode. All the vertices should already be selected. Press <kbd>W</kbd>  to bring up the Specials menu, and select the Bevel function (or select it directly with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>). As you move the mouse, you will see each vertex of the cube turn into a triangular face; don’t bother getting the shape exactly right, simply press <kbd>LMB</kbd> to finish the drag. Then, look in the panel that should have appeared at the bottom of the Toolshelf on the left of the 3D view (press <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle its visibility); you should see an editable numeric field labelled “Offset”. Type the value 1.0 into this field, and that should exactly form the octahedron shape. Finally, bring up the Specials menu again, and this time select Remove Doubles.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=1)
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

**Icosahedron**
Bring up the Add Mesh menu, and select an Icosphere. Set the Subdivision to 1. Simple!

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=1)
```

**Dodecahedron**
This shape is the dual of the icosahedron. To create it, make an icosahedron as above. Then do what you did to make an octahedron out of a cube: press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch to Edit mode. All the vertices should already be selected. Press <kbd>W</kbd> to bring up the Specials menu, and select the Bevel function. As with the octahedron, press <kbd>LBM</kbd> to finish the drag. Then set the Offset value to `0.607`, the closest I could find. Then, bring up the Specials menu again, and this time select Remove Doubles. However, the default Merge Distance of 0.0001 will not be enough to remove all the doubled vertices; change this to 0.001, and you should see the message “Removed 40 vertices” briefly flash up.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=1)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=0.607)
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=0.001)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

[Source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Platonic_Solids)